# SQL query two tables

Tags: sql

I have the following two tables...

```
Messages
ID   Title   Body
1    T1      B1 
4    T2      B2   
5    T3      B3  
6    T4      B4 
8    T5      B5
```

.

```
MessagesRead
UserName    ID
tom         1 
tom         4 
tom         8 
dick        5 
dick        6 
dick        8 
harry       4 
harry       5 
harry       6
```

I need to design a query that returns only the rows when the IDs don't match for a given person. For example...

Running this for 'tom' will return rows from 'Messages' with IDs 5 & 6. For 'dick', 1 & 4. And for 'harry', 1 & 8.

Hope this makes sense!

Comment: What do you want the output to contain and look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following query:

```
SELECT ID 
FROM Messages 
WHERE ID NOT IN (
    SELECT ID 
    FROM MessagesRead 
    WHERE UserName = 'your_input_name');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM messages 
WHERE id NOT IN (
    SELECT mr.id 
    FROM messagesread mr 
    WHERE username = 'tom'
)
```

**working sqlfiddle** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/c7b02/1

Note that I used WebSqlite db for simplicity.